# Datatables not loading

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I am trying to using datatables Jquery plugin in codeingiter but its not working please help me to debug

Heres my controller where I am calling my view:

```
  public function show_all_merchants()
        {
                $data["query"]= $this->details_model->get_mids();

                $this->load->view('show_merchants_view',$data);

        }
```

Heres my view:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function()
            {
              $('#example').dataTable
              ({
                'bProcessing'    : true,
                'bServerSide'    : true,
                'sAjaxSource'    : 'show_merchant_details',
                'iDisplayStart'  : 0,
                  'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
        {

         $.ajax 
          ({
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type'    : 'POST',
             'url'    : sSource,
             'data'  : aoData,
             'success' : fnCallback,
            'cache'   : false
          });
        }

              });
            });


    </script>


 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="example">
                                  <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                      <th width="20%">ID</th>
                                      <th width="25%">First Name</th>
                                      <th width="15%">Last Name</th>
                                      <th width="25%">Email</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>

                                  </thead>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td colspan="5">Loading data from server</td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>

 </table>
```

and heres my controller where I am loading the data Here I am loading data tables library:

```
 function show_merchant_details()
    {
                 $this->datatables
                 ->select('mid, merchant_name, merchant_link,merchant_contact')
                 ->from('merchants')
                 ->add_column('edit', '<a href="store/update/$1" title="Edit">Edit</a>', 'id')
                 ->add_column('delete', '<a href="store/delete/$1" title="Delete">Delete</a>', 'id');

               echo $this->datatables->generate();

    }
```

Friends  show_merchant_details() is wrking properly as i am able to see the output
In the view page I am able to see it like Loading data from server ...... (dats it)

Comment: How do you understand that it's not working? You have errors or what?

Comment: My Search:
Processing...
ID First Name Last Name Email  
Loading data from server this is the output

Comment: Loading data from server ..Its just showing me this text...

Comment: Do you see ajax-request in a debugger? What is `sSource`, what is `fnCallback`?

Comment: POST http://localhost/groce/show_merchant_details [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 28ms  I am geting this one in web console

Comment: `fnCallback` where it is defined?

Comment: {"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2,"aaData":[["1","flipcart","http:\/\/www.google.com","9948274112","<a href=\"store\/update\/id\" title=\"Edit\">Edit<\/a>","<a href=\"store\/delete\/id\" title=\"Delete\">Delete<\/a>"],["2","neel","http:\/\/www.google.com","9948274112","<a href=\"store\/update\/id\" title=\"Edit\">Edit<\/a>","<a href=\"store\/delete\/id\" title=\"Delete\">Delete<\/a>"]],"sColumns":"mid,merchant_name,merchant_link,merchant_contact,edit,delete"}<div id='codeigniter_profiler' style='clear:both;background-color:#fff;padding:10px;'>

Comment: `fnCallback` is a function. It's not a JSON.

Comment: i didnt get u .. what should be my step to rectify it

Comment: When ajax-request completed successfully function defined as `success` is being executed. In your code on `success` event `fnCallback` function is executed. So where is `fnCallback` defined? Do you have this function?

Comment: sorry @u_mulder I made a mistake .. I enabled profiler in my constructor so I was geting that error